# Certain DB entry gets ignored

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, undefined

This thing totally baffles me, I have a database with various entry, and for one particular entry name `415` (which also happens to be the last one, currently in the database), it is getting ignored and treated as non existent.

Here is my code:

```
/* database section start */
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","dbname");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
/* database section end */

// Choose Relevant Products, and turn them into an array
$item_array = array(
'417',
'415',
'446'
);

//implode items, turn into string
$item_implode = join("','", $item_array);

//declare an overall array for result
$product = array();

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name, WebsitePrice as price from products where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode');");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $product_name = $row['Name'];
    // find all keys in $item_array which value is the products
        $keys = array_keys($item_array, $product_name);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {

        // add values for these keys
        $product[$key + 1]["Name"] = $row['Name'];
        $product[$key + 1]["price"] = $row['price'];
    }
}

// test print all avaialable database values
for ($i=1; $i <= count($product)+2; $i++) { 
    echo $product[$i]["Name"] . " - "; //line 46
    echo $product[$i]["price"] . "<br/>"; //line 47
}
```

And my output:

> 417 - 2588.26
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   /home/saleturbo/public_html/lifetime-new6.php on line 46
>   -  Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/saleturbo/public_html/lifetime-new6.php on line 47
>
> 446 - 1654.39

This is relevant DB screenshot of `products` table:

[image]

As you can see, the `415` entry has values and is constructed just like other entries.

Comment: can you please add `$product_name = trim($row['Name']);` in your code and then try it.

Comment: i added it before `// test print all avaialable database values` line, nothing has changed.

Comment: you suppose to add at starting of `while` loop where you have declared `$product_name`

Comment: I mean to say `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $product_name = trim($row['Name']); }`

Comment: @JimishGamit that actually worked! can you explain why?

Comment: It's very simple. Edit `415` in phpMyAdmin. It is containing leading/trailing space. Added in answer. accept it :)

Comment: thanks! didn't noticed that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might that it having leading/trailing space

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $product_name = trim($row['Name']); 
    //rest of the code..
}
```